# addition with fixed min/max value

Tags: java, integer, overflow, modulo

major edit: 100% solved! it's called Modular arithmetic thanks Peter!!

i need to add two numbers with a fixed min/max value.
i want my numbers behave like java's int/byte/short (overflowing to its opposite value and continuing the operation)

```
System.out.println((byte) (Byte.MAX_VALUE));    // 127
System.out.println((byte)(Byte.MAX_VALUE + 1)); // -128
System.out.println((byte)(Byte.MAX_VALUE + 2)); // -127
System.out.println((byte)(Byte.MAX_VALUE + 3)); // -126
```

but with a fixed .MAX_VALUE and .MIN_VALUE.  if a number's value is 3 and it's maxValue is 5 and minValue is 2, then when i add 4 to it (3+4=should be 7) it overflows 
so 3+4: 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 2 -> 3
example:

```
    int value = 0, minValue = -2, maxValue = 1;
    MyNumber n = new MyNumber(value, minValue, maxValue);

    // possible values: -2 -1  0  1 -2 -1  0  1 -2 -1  0  1 ..

    n.add(2);   // 0+2 = -2
    n.add(-2);  // -2-2 = 0
    n.add(5);   // 0+5 = 1       
    n.add(-5);  // 1-5 = 0       
    n.add(-5);  // 0-5 = -1       
    n.add(-1);  // -1-1 = -2       
    n.add(11);  // -2+11 = 1
```

this is what i did:

```
class MyNumber {

    int value;
    final int minValue, maxValue;

    public MyNumber(int value, int minValue, int maxValue) {
        if (value < minValue || value > maxValue || maxValue < minValue) {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
        this.value = value;
        this.minValue = minValue;
        this.maxValue = maxValue;
    }

    void add(int amount) {
        int step = 1;
        if (amount < 0) {
            step = -1;
            amount = -amount;
        }
        while (amount-- > 0) {
            value += step;
            if (value < minValue)
                value = maxValue; // overflows
            if (value > maxValue)
                value = minValue; // overflows
        }
    }
}
```

it works but i don't want to iterate the whole addition since i'm going to work with big numbers
i think it has something to do with MOD... (i am terrible at maths)
nearly randomly i made this:

```
void add(int amount) {
    value = (value + amount) % (maxValue - minValue + 1);
}
```

i was so close but it fails at

```
n = new MyNumber(-2, -4, -1);
n.add(2); // -2+2 shows 0 instead of -4   (-2.. -1.. *overflow*.. -4)
```

i surrender

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Can you improve the wording?

Comment: In your modulos version, the "value" should be the offset from minValue, not the actual value. Correct your logic accordingly.

Comment: what is your question? or what is the problem your are facing?

Comment: i edited but i don't know how to make it more clear

Comment: it seems i am the only one who understood what you wanted, matias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to make things as clear as possible. e.g

If you want clock arithmetic you can do

```
   // in the constructor
   this.range = maxValue - minValue + 1;
   this.value = -minValue;

   // in the adder.
   public void add(int num) {
       value = (value + num) % range;
       if(value < 0) value += range;
       // or
       value = ((value + num) % range + range) % range;
   }


   // add a getter for value.
   public int getValue() { return value + minValue; };
```

---

If you wanted bounded arithmetic.

```
    value = Math.min(maxValue, Math.max(minValue, value + step));
```

Comment: that will stop the addition after overflowing. if you have max_value=2, that will do 0+3=2 which is wrong. when it reaches value=2 it goes 0, but it must not stop the addition. 0+3=1->2->0

Comment: I missed you wanted clock arithmetic. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
value += amount;

value = value > maxValue ? maxValue : value < minValue ? minValue : value;
```

This should work.

Change :

```
range = maxValue == minValue ? 0 : Math.abs(maxValue - minValue + 1);
value = range == 0 ? maxValue : value + amount <= maxValue && value + amount >= minValue ? value + amount : value + amount > maxValue ? minValue + (((value + amount - maxValue) % range) == 0 ? range : (value + amount - maxValue) % range) - 1 : maxValue - ((Math.abs(amount) - Math.abs(value - minValue + 1)) % range);
```

Comment: that will stop the addition after overflowing. your logic is saying Byte.MAX_VALUE + 3 equals Byte.MIN_VALUE. and it's not true

Comment: Sorry, i misunderstood the question. Now i got it. I have changed accordingly. Please check.

Comment: can you please mention what are the max and min values in the case you tested it on

Comment: for value = -2, minValue = -2, maxValue = 1 adding - 2 returns -4. out of range

Comment: fixed it. also fixed case when minValue=maxValue. Sorry it looks a bit complicated. If you want i can provide a simplified version, but first check for its proper functioning. Inform accordingly

Comment: by simplified version i meant using if-else statements

Comment: very good approach but it fails when overflowing twice+... value = 0, minValue = -2, maxValue = 1, amount = 5 (amount>range) that is returning -3 isntead of 1 . . . (0) -> 1 -> -2 -> -1 -> 0 -> 1

Comment: oh well it didn't OF twice but fails when amount>range

Comment: I was just checking Peter's solution. It does not seem to work when minValue=maxValue. For example minValue=maxValue=3. In this case value can only be equal to 3. Try adding 5 to it. Does it work or I am wrong somewhere?

Comment: im trying to figure it out how to use it exactly. why would you test it against a number with an unique possible value?

Comment: Is that not a use case? What if the possible range set has only element?

Comment: if a number has only a single possible value then you can't make use of it

Answer (score 0):

Ok !

You will not like this but it enables you to avoid the addition operation:

(Notice the code is in C# as i dont have java here) It looks like this:

```
class MyNumber 
{    
    public int value;
    int minValue, maxValue;
    private int[] range; 
    private int index = 0;

    //Ctor
    public MyNumber(int value, int minValue, int maxValue) 
    {
        if (value < minValue || value > maxValue || maxValue < minValue)            
            throw new Exception("...");

        this.value = value;
        this.minValue = minValue;
        this.maxValue = maxValue;
        range = new int[maxValue - minValue + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < range.Length; i++)
        {
            range[i] = minValue;
            if (range[i] == value)
                index = i;
            minValue++;
        }
    }

    public void add(int amount)
    {
        if (Math.Abs(amount) > range.Length)
            amount %= range.Length;

        index = Math.Abs(index + amount);
        if (index >= range.Length)
            index %= range.Length;

        value = range[index];
    }
}
```